# how to use root directory for multiple repos in git?

Tags: github

I would like to create below folder structure in git in order to organise my projects better.

```
Dojo (root)
   - proj/repo 1
   - proj/repo 2

Node (root)
   - proj/repo 1
   - proj/repo 2
   - proj/repo 3
```

Is it feasible?

Comment: You could setup a main repo that tracks multiple submodules.